# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name" (template: "/_header" - line 10, col 46)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

when I run https://localhost:8080
Im getting above error in console

Comment: you could use ```<span sec:authentication="name"></span>``` if you want to display the userPrincipal

Comment: In the error message it will tell you why there was an exception evaluating that expression.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
This is the error

Comment: 2019-05-01 07:47:04.609 ERROR 16632 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name" (template: "/_header" - line 10, col 46)] with root cause

Comment: <div class="header-container" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
   <div class="site-name">Online Shop</div>
   <div class="header-bar">
      <th:block sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
         Hello <a th:href="@{/admin/accountInfo}" th:utext="${#request.userPrincipal.name}">..</a>
         &nbsp;|&nbsp;
         <a th:href="@{/admin/logout}">Logout</a>
      </th:block>
      <th:block sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
         <a th:href="@{/admin/login}">Login</a>
      </th:block>
   </div>
</div>